# C#, Linq Search Dictionary in C# and return string using key

Tags: c#, string, linq, dictionary

I have dictionary created as

```
Dictionary<string, string> delta = new dictionary<string, string>();
        delta.Add("A", "One");
        delta.Add("B", "Two");
        delta.Add("C", "Three");
```

I wanted to retrieve value based on the value passed as key

```
public string GetValuefromdictionary(string roll. Dictionary<string, string> delta)
{       
    string rollValue;
    return rollValue = delta
        .Where(d => d.Key.Contains(roll))
        .Select(d =>   d.Value)
        .ToString();
}
```

however I am seeing it doesn't return me the string and I get like this

``` System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator``2[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair``2[System.String,System.String],System.String] ```

any help

Comment: `value based on the value passed as key` not clear, realy

Comment: I think what you're searching for is `return delta[roll];`

Comment: if you want to get value by key you should you `[ ]` operator. `delta["A"] ` returns you `"One"`

Comment: `Contains` doesn't make sense for a single character string.  Maybe you meant to find the value where the `roll` value contains that letter?

Comment: Are Dictionary values unique?

Comment: The result of your LINQ is an enumerable collection of strings, not a single string - calling `ToString` on this is just going to return the name of the class, the default for all classes that do not override `ToString`.

Answer (score 0):

if a Key is "ABC", and you pass "A" as roll, and you want to return the value from "ABC" because "ABC" contains "A". You can do this:

```
  return delta.FirstOrDefault(d=> d.Key.Contains(roll)).Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options, better I would say two cases.

**Case 1**

Let's say `Dictionary` Values are unique, in this case we can simply transpose the dictionary swapping `<Key,Value>`  pair.

```
var transformDictionary = delta.ToDictionary(kp => kp.Value, kp => kp.Key);
```

Now we can access this like any other dictioanry.

```
transformDictionary["One"];
```

**Case 2 :**

Values are not unique, in this case use LookUp.

```
var lookup = delta.ToLookup(c=>c.Value, c=>c.Key);      
var lookupvalue = ((IEnumerable<string>)lookup["One"]).First();
```

Working [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tBlupT)

Comment: Why down vote? please specify the reason, answer can be improved.

Answer (score -1):

> You want to search for an element in a Dictionary, but using value instead of > a key. So you iterate through you dictionary and return the
>   first element that has the value you are looking for. The output you
>   get is a keyValue pair, hence the .Key

```
string key = "One";
string value = delta.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Value.Contains(key)).Key;
```

Comment: Please explain why your code fragment answers the question